# Serialization in MVVM pattern WPF objects

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I have an application and I have around 20+ pages and am creating all pages at the starting of the application. It might be a memory over flow exception in future.? Whether it is a better Idea or can pages as I need.

Comment: Last sentience is unclear. Although if you show all 20 window (pages more suited name for the Web) that seems like a bad idea, you should have one main window and open modal only when needed. User most likely would work with 1 active window - not 20 active windows.

Comment: @Vladimir See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where is the serialization question here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those pages are created only once, then the memory usage for them wont change. Any objects you create on those pages will cause the memory consumption to increase.

As for your question, creating the pages at the start of the application should be fine, just beware that you will have to create them in such a way that the Garbage Collection will not clear them out of memory. Also make sure you don't create new instances of them each time they are displayed :)